# require_once not working to external file

Tags: php, require-once

I have a page that I am trying to pull data into from msqsql DB. I got it to work with hep of some folks on this site. I tried to change where the connection variables are tp point to a config file.\, and I don't even get an error to go off of.  I have another file that is using require_once to point to the same config file and it works fine but it's a much more complicated string.  I thought I could just copy the require_once to set this on my page but Im missing something.

Example of my page that works but I don't want the connection string directly on this page.

/*connection link */

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "un", "pw", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$type = "mixers";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT record_number, Base_Price FROM Products
WHERE Unit_Product='u'")) {

/* bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $type);

/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $product, $price);

/* fetch value */
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {     
$products[$product] = $price;    }



/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);

?>

<?php echo $products['1014']; ?>
```

Below is Example of my parts page that works with require_once.  I tried to copy this entire code and then I'd pair it down later, but I don't even get an error.

```
        <?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('./inc/functions.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['catid']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['catid'])) {
$cat_rn = $_REQUEST['catid'];
display_category($cat_rn);
} else {
echo 'Invalid catid provided. <a href="/">Return Home</a> try something like 
<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?catid=140">'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?catid=140</a>';

}

function display_category($cat_rn) {
    require_once('./inc/db_config.php');
    require_once('./inc/functions.php');
    $con = mysql_connect($catdb['host'],$catdb['user'],$catdb['pass']);
    if (!is_resource($con))
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($catdb['dbname'], $con);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I knew to php but I'm learning a lot.
-Michael

Comment: You should probably add all the paths of the files by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `require_once()`.  The scope of that "once" is **UNIVERSAL**. As soon as you `require_once()` that file ANYWHERE in your script, all other `require_once()` for the same file are going to become no-OPS and skip the file:

inc.php:

```
<?php
echo 'hello';
```

script.php:

```
<?php
require_once('inc.php');   // runs, prints "hello";

function foo() {
   require_once('inc.php'); // require SKIPPED because file already included
}

foo();
```

The above code would print `hello` only ONCE.

If you want to include/require the file multiple times, then you CAN'T use the _once() variant.

Comment: it is also probably worth noting that for files like `function.php`, including that file in the global scope and again elsewhere will cause a fatal error because the functions have already been defined and can't be re-defined which is why require_once is usually used.